# Cannot find where to place code to load an external CSS file into Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: css, adobe-edge

I've searched high and low for this but cannot figure this out based on what I've found. It seems that something along these lines is the way to go

```
$("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mystyle.css'>").appendTo("#Stage");
```

Where does this code need to be placed? I've tried everywhere in the 'full code' field, but it doesn't show up in the source code when published.

I need to write media queries to make my project respond in a pretty bespoke way and I think pulling in an external stylesheet is the only way to do it. Unless there is a way of adding custom CSS in the edge interface somehow? Can't find anything referencing this though

I've tried putting the queries into the  of the html doc itself which of course works but gets wiped whenever republished!

Comment: Just add the external CSS link to the outputted HTML just like you would a normal page.

Comment: I was trying that, as well as hard coding the styles into html page and until now every time I published from Edge it would wipe it completely. Just tried it again and it now works!!! Really strange, no idea why this is...